# Unable to create new user in my webapp even though loging in works fine

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, directus

When trying to register a new user in my web app my post request says i dont have permission to access this. I have no issues loging in to my webapp with a user i already made in the User role in Directus.

I have read the doumentation and as far as i can see, ive done everything correctly. Is this a bug, or is there something i should have in mind, cause it feels like ave tried everything.

Comment: Don't post images, post your actual error messages and code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.